# Return multiple "parent" (header) values based on "child" (input) values with concatenate function

Tags: excel

Here is the formula I have currently.
This returns **one** of the header values I need, as there is an "X" located below that header value. 
How do I return another header value if there's an "X" value below it?

`=INDEX('Sheet1'!$O$5:$U$5,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(('Sheet1'!$O7:$U7="X")*(COLUMN('Sheet1'!$O7:$U7))-COLUMN('Sheet1'!$O$5)+1)))`

Headers are located in cells: `O5:U5` and values are located in cells: `O7:U7`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the **array formula**:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(O7:Q7="x",O5:Q5,""))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Do I need a VBA script for this to work? If I'm referencing another sheet, does that make a difference in the formula? I'm getting a #NAME error.

Comment: @user8421296 the **#NAME?** error means that your version of Excel  does not include the `TEXTJOIN()` function ....................sorry...........